# Ent. how to remove a column?

Tags: go, ent

I have already an Ent model in my go project. But I need to remove some columns from the model.
It not works when I update my model. Running migration results runtime error.
How can I remove a column from existing model in Ent. ORM?

Answer (score 1):

You can change model simply to remove some fields and this will works if you set `WithDropIndex` and `WithDropColumn` options within migration as follow:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    
    "<project>/ent"
    "<project>/ent/migrate"
)

func main() {
    client, err := ent.Open("mysql", "root:pass@tcp(localhost:3306)/test")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed connecting to mysql: %v", err)
    }
    defer client.Close()
    ctx := context.Background()
    // Run migration.
    err = client.Schema.Create(
        ctx, 
        migrate.WithDropIndex(true),
        migrate.WithDropColumn(true), 
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed creating schema resources: %v", err)
    }
}
```

For more information [see documentation](https://entgo.io/docs/migrate#drop-resources)